# How to add time as a feature into word embeddings?

Tags: text-mining, nlp, plotting

I have a text corpus and I'm using TfidfVectorizer. Would it be possible to cluster the resultant matrix once I concatenate tf-idf vector and time feature matrix I built([year, month, day])?

I'm also working around using word2vec for plotting a graph of similar words and I want to add time dimension for these plots.

*Example: Let's say, I've five popular bug areas and for these five areas, I'm plotting similar words from the corpus using Word2Vec and Plotly. I want to have time filters on my plot such that I should be able to see these plots for different years. If my entire corpus has data from past four years then I want to visualize it for a particular year based on user selection.*

I'm not sure how to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: What is a "bug area"?

Comment: @desertnaut The bug area is a word from Word2Vec vocabulary for which I'm plotting similar words. I have generated a list of words which I have marked as potential bug areas.